# How to use .NET 6 Preview Generic Math in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio-2022, c#-10.0

There are several articles explaining the new .NET 6 Preview features of Generic Math, often based on this Microsoft article:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/preview-features-in-net-6-generic-math/

In the preview versions, and the first release of Visual Studio 2022 this works fine.  But in Visual Studio 2022 version 17.0.3 and 17.0.4 (the current release) I simply cannot get this to compile.

I actually went back to VS2022 version 17.0.0 to make sure I had correctly followed the article steps.  The code compiles just fine.  Upgrade to VS2022 version 17.0.3 and the same project fails to build with the error:

```
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'INumber<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Anyone got any ideas?  I assume I have to make a further change to the csproj file, but what change?

In the NuGet Package Manager I found the option to upgrade System.Runtime.Experimental to version 6.0.0, which changed the entry in my csproj file from:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.Experimental" Version="6.0.0-preview.7.21377.19" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

to:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.Experimental" Version="6.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

rebooting doesn't help.  Cleaning the solution doesn't help. I am not seeing anything to help me in the release notes for Visual Studio 2022 either.

The complete csproj file, for reference, already containing the extra bits you need, is:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <EnablePreviewFeatures>True</EnablePreviewFeatures>
        <LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.Experimental" Version="6.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: There is a [very long thread](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/pull/205) about the design problems, pushed back to [.net7](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/pull/257) but with no milestone yet.

Comment: Those features are clearly marked `Preview`. There's no guarantee they'll work from one VS version to the next, especially if they've been pushed back. Instead of leaving half-baked features, the .NET team may have decided to remove them, especially if development has stopped

Answer (score 1):

#### Step 1

As explained in the blog article you've linked at the top of the question: add

```
    <EnablePreviewFeatures>true</EnablePreviewFeatures>
```

into a `<PropertyGroup>` element in your project file.

#### Step 2

Now the above is confirmed: have you tried the preview version of VS2022 (currently V17.1 Preview 1.1)?

Just tried it: No.

#### Step 3

See [Hans Passant's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) comment on to the question: need to wait on this (or do you own builds of what is being built to be .NET 7...)

### Update for VS 2002 17.2.0 Preview 3.0

With V6.0.2 of System.Runtime.Experimental this now works.

Comment: Already done, required to get it to compile in Visual Studio 2022 version 17.0.0.  Nothing changed in the project between version 17.0.0 and 17.0.3, but the project stops compiling.

Comment: Updated:  looks like it will be a wait for this to be in anything other than private builds...

Comment: Updated #2: works on my machine with latest preview version of VS, latest NuGet dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error with VS2022 17.0.4. Now, VS2022 17.1.0 Preview 1.1 seems to work fine.